# jQuery Validation Plugin - equalTo not working

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I'm trying to use the equalTo method with the jQuery Validation Plugin (http://jqueryvalidation.org/equalTo-method) but it's not working. Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong?

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="email-again" id="email-again" placeholder="Confirm Email" class="ss-q-short" required />
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
$("#ss-form").validate({

   rules: {
   entry_123: "required",
       email-again: {
       equalTo: "#entry_123"
       }
   }



}); // end of function validate
}); //end of general function

</script>
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Please show all relevant HTML markup.  I don't see your `#entry_123` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    $("#ss-form").validate({
        rules: {
            entry_123: "required",
            "email-again": {
                equalTo: "#entry_123"
            }
        }
    }); // end of function validate
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rpqJL/)

Comment: @user2528845 checkout the demo

Comment: @user2528845 check the browser console to see whether there is any error

Comment: @user2528845 also can you share the form you are working with... whether the required validation is working there?

Comment: Hm it says "Uncaught Syntaxerror Unexpected Number" - but I don't see any errors in my code...?

Comment: @user2528845 there is your problem... look at the line number and file which is throwing the error

Comment: Got it!!!  I was missing a comma after the bracket.  (I had more code in there that I didn't display in my block of code on this site, and I was missing the comma to break between the different parts of the code.)

Comment: Nice fix. Who would of thought putting the ID name in " " would work to target the element ID? I was having issues because I could not use the object name (generated by CMS system).

Comment: The whole problem was caused by not having the hyphenated name within quotation marks.   `"email-again"`  The answer should be more clear.